# Class arguments not being passed

Tags: 10

Updating the emulsify_twig extension for D10, for some reason the class arguments aren't being passed... I'm extending Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension and using the same default arguments but for some reason it isn't picking up the arguments, resulting in: `ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Drupal\emulsify_twig\BemTwigExtension::__construct(), 0`

This is the relevant code from the class:

```
use Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Render\RendererInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatterInterface;
use Drupal\Core\File\FileUrlGeneratorInterface;

class BemTwigExtension extends TwigExtension {
  protected $urlGenerator;  
  protected $renderer;  
  protected $themeManager;  
  protected $dateFormatter;  
  protected $fileUrlGenerator;

  public function __construct(RendererInterface $renderer, UrlGeneratorInterface $url_generator, ThemeManagerInterface $theme_manager, DateFormatterInterface $date_formatter, FileUrlGeneratorInterface $file_url_generator = NULL) {
    parent::__construct(
      $renderer,
      $url_generator,
      $theme_manager,
      $date_formatter,
      $file_url_generator
    );
    
    $this->renderer = $renderer;
    $this->urlGenerator = $url_generator;
    $this->themeManager = $theme_manager;
    $this->dateFormatter = $date_formatter;
    $this->fileUrlGenerator = $file_url_generator;
  }
```

Any insight as to why the arguments aren't being passed would be appreciated!

Comment: We would have to see the code that is instantiating the object. Is this a a service? Can we see the service definition please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message states that no arguments are being passed to the Twig filter extension. Drupal Twig filter extensions must be defined in `[MODULE].services.yml`, and in that service definition, the services to be injected as dependencies are defined. These are the arguments that `BemTwigExtension::__construct` is expecting, but not finding.

You *could* do something like the followingin `emulsify_twig.services.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  emulsify_twig.bem_twig_extension:
    class: Drupal\emulsify_twig\TwigExtension\BemTwigExtension
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
    arguments:
      - '@renderer'
      - '@url_generator'
      ...
```

Entering all the dependencies using their service definition names.

However, in the original post, as `__construct` is passing the arguments to the parent, the parent service definition can be referenced to determine which arguments it expects. In the original ploblem [TwigExtension](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21TwigExtension.php/class/TwigExtension/9.4.x) is being extended, and the `TwigExtension` API page lists one service as using it: [twig.extension](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/twig.extension/9.4.x). Viewing the source on `twig.extension` API page shows the services expected by the parent class (the `arguments`):

```yaml
class: Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension
arguments:
  - '@renderer'
  - '@url_generator'
  - '@theme.manager'
  - '@date.formatter'
  - '@file_url_generator'
tags:
  - { name: twig.extension, priority: 100 }
```

Then, instead of redefining all these arguments in the extended service definition, the parent can be set, using its arguments and tags as a base. So, back to `emulsify_twig.services.yml` the service would be defined as follows:

```yaml
services:
  emulsify_twig.bem_twig_extension:
    class: Drupal\emulsify_twig\TwigExtension\BemTwigExtension
    parent: twig.extension
    arguments:
      - '@additional_class.1'
      ...
```

Where `@additional_class.1` is the name of any additional services that the extended class will use, that the parent does not. Note that if the extended class does not require any additional services, the `__construct()` method does not need to be implemented in the extended class at all, as the parent implementation will be used when not defined in the child class. However, the service will still need to be defined in `emulsify_twig.services.yml` with the parent set as `twig.extension`.

Comment: Setting the `parent` key in services was the missing piece... and removing the constructor cuts the amount of code in half - thanks!

Comment: You also don't need to declare the protected properties, as the parent defines them as well.

Comment: Yep- the only lines I kept were the class declaration & use TwigExtension, then added  parent in services... thanks again!